# HTTP Send Post-Request fails

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl, http-post

I am trying to get staff information like name and email using GID but the following Errors appears while trying to send Post request.

> Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake
>
> at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO',
>   syscall: 'write' }

this is how my code looks like

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'deprecated',
    'accepted':     'application/json',
    'applicationuser':'deprecated'

}
// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'https://***/***/persons/gid=***',
    method: 'POST',
    secureProtocol : "TLSv1_2_method",
    headers: headers
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
    else{console.log(error)}
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3692

Comment: @james what do you think the solution should be? is there any thing to add to the snippet code above ?

Comment: It points to a problem with certain versions of openSSL having difficulty downgrading a connection when trying to connect through a load balancer to a group of servers that don't all have the same version of TLS.  I don't know if upgrading to a newer openSSL will fix it but I'd give it a go.

Comment: how can i try to upgrade the version of openSSL? i am just new with this topic :(

Comment: I've never done it.  I would google it.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the response; actually the route function response this. Usually it is because you need a certificate is not the correct one.
You can check more about it [Solving sslv3 alert handshake failure when trying to use a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370656/solving-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-when-trying-to-use-a-client-certificate)

Comment: what do you think the solution should be? is there any thing to add to the snippet code above ?

Comment: you need to check the documentation of your client, or the web you're trying to do