# Error sending iOS push notifications using PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm getting the following error when trying to send 'Push Notifications' connecting APNS using PHP:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed 

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
```

Here is my code:

```
$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $message . '","sound":"default"}}';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Certificate.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',      $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: get us your php code :P

Comment: Yes, please share your code.

Comment: It sounds like you lack (1) TLS 1.0 and above, (2) Server Name Indication, and (3) possibly the *Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)* root. Also see [“verify error:num=20” when connecting to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23351633/608639)

Comment: @jww Thank you. Missing Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048) was the problem. Added this line after downloading the Entrust Root Certifcate `stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');`. Notifications works fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Root certificate](https://www.entrust.com/get-support/ssl-certificate-support/root-certificate-downloads/) and adding the following line fixed the issue

```
`stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask you Server admin to open port `2195` or `2196` for outgoing connections. It will solve you issue.

Comment: Thank you Kenil.. Even if the ports are open, without `entrust_2048_ca.cer`, it runs into error:14090086